# ECFAugie handwritten blackboard look with xelatex polyglossia in Beamer

Tags: beamer, polyglossia

It is needed to use the ECFAugie handwritten blackboard look with xelatex polyglossia in Beamer. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\title{Taller de Musixtex}
\subtitle{Una introducción para Músicos}

\begin{document}

% set handwritten font
\ECFAugie

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{\ECFAugie Musixtex}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Musixtex is a Latex package.
        \item It is focus on music.
        \item It is very usefull.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The expected output is as follow (note that is needed to use the poliglossia with spanish language):
[image: expected]

Comment: polyglossia resets the fontencoding. So at every call you would need to change that `\fontencoding{T1}\ECFAugie`. But be aware that T1 is not a suitable encoding for xetex, various accented chars can be wrong. It would be better to find a open type handwriting font.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why this question got a downvote. IMHO it is one of the better questions we see on this site. It gives compilable code which can be copy&pasted to reproduce the problem, it shows what the desired result looks like, has a title which describes the problem and uses the relevant tags. What more can be expected from a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using xelatex you could use fontspec if you have augie installed as a system font (I'd also suggest to use babel instead of polyglossia).

It might also be a good idea to consider using lualatex instead of xelatex, which sometimes causes problems with beamer.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{augie}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\title{Taller de Musixtex}
\subtitle{Una introducción para Músicos}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Musixtex}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Musixtex is a Latex package.
        \item It is focus on music.
        \item It is very usefull.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it would be wrong with babel too if you load fontspec (or use \babelfont).

Comment: Is your recommendation not to use polyglossia specifically because of Beamer? Or something more general?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added a second approach with fontspec directly loading augie

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the second version is much better (I didn't know that there is augie font).

Comment: @scottkosty I'd generally use babel instead of polyglossia. babel works fine with all engines, seems to cause less headaches and after a bit of a break a couple of years ago, now seems to be very actively maintained.

Comment: @scottkosty I prefer babel too, imho babel is much more active currently (but I'm naturally biased as babel is maintained in the latex3 github).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I removed the first approach. Augie is available on many sites, e.g. https://www.dafont.com/augie.font (can't remember where I got it from)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good to know! This surprises me since I find the open (14) to closed (386) ratio of issues in polyglossia especially impressive. But I have zero knowledge about these packages so I appreciate your advice.

Comment: @scottkosty if you compare the babel news https://latex3.github.io/babel/news/whats-new-in-babel-3.85.html with the revision history in the polyglossia manual, you can see that both fix errors but that babel adds more new features especially for lualatex and bidi support.

Comment: @scottkosty For a short comparison, you can see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, I see what you mean!

Comment: @JavierBezos This is a great reference. I will look through it. Thanks!